# Pretty print in MongoDB shell as default

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface, mongo-shell

Is there a way to tell Mongo to pretty print output? Currently, everything is output to a single line and it's difficult to read, especially with nested arrays and documents.

Comment: Now: how do you print it from external javascript loaded into Mongo?

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba Try searching for the answer to your question. If you don't find an answer, go ahead and post it as a new question.

Comment: If you want colorized output and beautiful logging with MongoDB and Ruby on Rails, you can checkout https://github.com/ibraheemdev/mongo_beautiful_logger

Answer (score 952, accepted):

(*note: this is answer to original version of the question, which did not have requirements for "default"*)

You can ask it to be pretty.

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
```

Comment: If you want output colorized + other enhancements check out https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker @SAFX

Comment: Now: how do you print it from external javascript loaded into Mongo? This will not work...

Comment: Eureka!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 438):

You can add

```
DBQuery.prototype._prettyShell = true
```

to your file in `$HOME/.mongorc.js` to enable pretty print globally by default.

Comment: You'll want to make a custom function that disables it for you. Add this to your `$HOME/.mongorc.js`: https://gist.github.com/mathrawka/6239405  Then you can do something like db.users.find().ugly() to get it without pretty print.

Comment: +1 This is great. For those who doesn't have a .mongorc.js file in $HOME folder; you can create this file and add commands in it. After you restart shell, it works!

Comment: How can I verify in a cli or in mongo shell that this option has been enabled? I mean, is there a special command for it, like `mongo --checkConf 'pretty'`, not by calling `db.collection.find().limit(1)`

Comment: @staackuser2, that link seems to be broken :(

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the question is pointed to: how to make this a default option. The user is already familiar with the .pretty() method but does not want to write it every time

Comment: Would be nice if this was set to true by default

Answer (score 63):

*(note: this is answer to the updated question)*

You can just do this on the CLI:

```
echo DBQuery.prototype._prettyShell = true >> ~/.mongorc.js
```

And it's always going to output pretty results.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. |
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7 and Oh-My-Zsh [version e55c715](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/e55c715508a2f652fed741f2047c66dda2c6e5b0)

Answer (score 23):

Since it is basically a javascript shell, you can also use `toArray()`:

```
db.collection.find().toArray()
```

However, this will print all the documents of the collection unlike `pretty()` that will allow you to iterate.
Refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

Comment: Interestingly enough, from the console the `.toArray()` function outputs better formatted JSON than the `.pretty()` function. ie: The first record of my collection is different than the rest (which may be the problem), but `.pretty()` dumps it out as `{ "_id" : "VERSION", "v" : "1.5" }` - all on one line, where `.toArray()` formatted it nice like the rest of the records..

Answer (score 19):

Oh so i guess .pretty() is equal to:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(printjson);
```

Answer (score 9):

Give a try to Mongo-hacker(node module), it alway prints pretty.
https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker

More it enhances mongo shell (supports only ver>2.4, current ver is 3.0), like

- Colorization
- Additional shell commands (count documents/count docs/etc)
- API Additions (db.collection.find({ ... }).last(), db.collection.find({ ... }).reverse(), etc)
- Aggregation Framework

I am using for while in production env, no problems yet.

Comment: What if I don't have mongodb, just installed meteor?

Comment: Note: when you install mongo-hacker using npm, it apparently overwrites `$HOME/.mongorc.js`.

Answer (score 6):

Got to the question but could not figure out how to print it from externally-loaded mongo. So:

**This works is for console:** and is prefered in console, but does not work in external mongo-loaded javascript:

```
db.quizes.find().pretty()
```

**This works in external mongo-loaded javscript:**

```
db.quizes.find().forEach(printjson)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
```