# Is there any way to see the mongo results in a better format?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to see the mongo results in a better format, like we are using \G in the sql ?

Comment: Do you mean [pretty printing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9146646/125816)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Andre solution,
in case you want to get only one element. You can use findOne function. It pretty prints that document.

```
db.test.findOne()
```

Also you can use toArray over a cursor. Though its a memory hog, but for small number of results its fine and pretty prints,

```
db.test.find({...}).toArray()
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to enable vertical printing like what you would see in \G in MySQL.  In the context that view is less useful, since MongoDB is a document store and can have nested documents and the like.

You can print out the results of a query in pretty printing, by adding a `.pretty()` to the query:

```
db.test.find().pretty()
```

Which will return the results in a expanded document view, which may be helpful.

Comment: Nice one, this is as close as it gets to the MySQL way.